# Who do I have to play to beat everyone in Dice in Flotsam?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm trying to get the she-troll head but the guy that has it won't play dice with me because I'm not good enough. I've already defeated the people at the inn. I also know that the the dwarf book trader won't play me.

Who and in which order am I supposed to play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must beat two guys (Casmir and Bendeck) at the Inn before the third (Sindram) will play you.  Must beat him before the dwarf bookseller (Einar Gausler) will play you.  Must beat him before you can play Sendler (found in Lobinden village to the east of Flotsam).
Beating Sendler makes you the best in Flotsam and completes a side-quest (Poker Face: Flotsam) and he'll offer you the troll head as a reward.

Comment: For more clarification: Sendler is the leatherworker in Lobinden

Comment: My question - is there a way to get the troll-head from him if you did the dice poker quest first and already took a trap design reward from him?

Comment: Turns out I hadn't beaten Sindram when I thought I had. Odd.